# C# Calling C function crash when using LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress

Tags: c#, .net, dll, interop, marshalling

I need to dynamically load DLL and invoke its methods

C code header:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int Init_Normalization_EN(char* path);
__declspec(dllexport) const char* Process_Normalization_EN(char* input);
```

C# code using [extern] to statically define library and methods:

```
[DllImport("TextNormalization_EN.dll", EntryPoint = "?Init_Normalization_EN@@YAHPAD@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int Init_Normalization_EN(IntPtr path);

[DllImport("TextNormalization_EN.dll", EntryPoint = "?Process_Normalization_EN@@YAPBDPAD@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr Process_Normalization_EN(IntPtr input);
```

When these declarations are used, interop works fine (for both init and process of normalization), but I need to point to a DLL dynamically, so I use the following code:

in the class-level:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private delegate int CallInit(IntPtr ipFolder);
private CallInit Init = null;

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private delegate IntPtr CallNormalize(IntPtr ipInput);
private CallNormalize Normalize = null;
```

in the constructor:

```
IntPtr pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(libraryPath);
IntPtr pAddressOfInit = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, InitName);
Init = (CallInit)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfInit, typeof(CallInit));

IntPtr pAddressOfNormalize = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, NormalizeName);
Normalize = (CallNormalize)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pDll, typeof(CallNormalize));

IntPtr pFolder = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(dataFolderPath);
int result = this.Init(pFolder);
if (result != 0)
{
    InitializeCompleted = true;
}
```

all this code runs OK and even the call to init the normalizer with a folder-path works fine (returns a handle non-zero)
but
when I try to run the text-normalizer:

```
IntPtr pInput = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(text);
IntPtr pResult = this.Normalize(pInput);
```

I get on the second line an application-level exception (that cannot be caught by try/catch):
"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Which is as far as I can understand caused by the returned string which I try to get as IntPtr as in the [extern] declaration

Comment: CharSet.Unicode is wrong, it is Ansi.  The first argument to GetDelegateForFunctionPointer must be the address of the function you obtained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't this line:

```
Normalize = (CallNormalize)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
    pDll,
    typeof(CallNormalize));
```

be

```
Normalize = (CallNormalize)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
    pAddressOfNormalize,
    typeof(CallNormalize));
```

Comment: WOW! It was a typo! I just don't beleive I spent a whole day trying to understand it